# Rate limit on guild.roles.create?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My project involves checking a json with course data and creating roles for each course. This worked fine the first few times but after making a few errors, deleting and recreating, the roles aren't being created.

**Update roles command:**
Essentially the roles get fetched once so multiple fetch requests aren't needed.

```
const guild = interaction.guild;

        await guild.roles.fetch();
        const rolesAdded = Array.from(guild.roles.cache.values()).map((r) => { return r.name; });

        for(const d of getDisciplines()){
            const roles = getDiscplineRoles(d);
            for(const r of roles){
                if(rolesAdded.includes(r[0])) continue;
                let colour;
                if(r[1] == "M"){
                    colour = "Purple";
                } else if (r[1] == "S"){
                    colour = "Blue";
                }

                addRole(guild, r[0], colour);
                rolesAdded.push(r[0]);

            }

            let courses = getCourses(d);
            courses = courses.map((c) => {
                return c[0];
            });

            for(const course of courses){
                if(rolesAdded.includes(course)) continue;
                addRole(interaction.guild, course, "LightGrey");
                rolesAdded.push(course);
            }
            

        }
        
        await interaction.reply("Roles created");
```

**addRole function:**
The console.log runs fine so i know this works

```
    addRole: async function(guild, roleName, colour) {
        // Get role and create if it doesn't exist
        const role = await guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === roleName);

        if (role !== undefined){
            return;
        }

        console.log(`${roleName} does not exists`);

        await guild.roles.create({
            name: roleName,
            color: colour,
        });

    }
```

I have tried looking up something about a limit but have only found 2 forum posts mentioning 2 numbers, 250 and 1000.
Note: No error is returned at all, the program just seems to be waiting for the request to be filled

Links:

- https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1480
- https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360050533812-Extreme-rate-limits-on-the-role-create-endpoint

Comment: You can add the rest client ratelimit event to your code like so: `client.rest.on("rateLimited", console.log);` (preferably in your index/main js file). This will log any ratelimit to your console. If it doesn't log anything you're not being ratelimited.

Comment: @Tetie, Thanks this helped a ton, was indeed being rate limited, specifically 250 role creates, just could not find any info online about this specific handle